# Zwei Stück oder Zwei Stücke?

Tags: grammatical-number

Ich lebe seit April des vergangenen Jahres in Österreich und versuche Deutsch zu lernen.
Normalerweise nehme ich auf, was ich höre, ohne in dieser Anfangsphase zu diskutieren, aber es gibt Dinge, die mich neugierig machen und ich bin auch immer unsicher, wenn ich "Österreichisch" und nicht Deutsch lerne.

Frage über „das Stück (die Stücke)“:
Warum sagen Leute (zumindest hier) "zwei, drei, ... Stück" und nicht " zwei, drei ... Stücke?". Nichtsdestoweniger sagen sie: "Wie viele Stücke willst du?"

Comment: Interessante Frage, genügt dir hier die Antwort vom Duden? https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Stueck#Bedeutung2

Comment: Oder alternativ [canoo.net, Maß- und Mengenangaben](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Nomen/Numerus/Menge.html), hier Abschnitt "Singular oder Plural".

Comment: Wenn du in Österreich lebst, was ist denn dann falsch die dort gängige Ausdrücke und Wendungen zu brauchen?

Comment: @Beta Aiwen fragt ja lediglich nach dem *Warum*, niemand hat etwas von falsch gesagt.

Answer (score 22):

"Stück" kann genauso wie z.B. "Glas" zum einen als Mass- oder Mengeneinheit für normalerweise unzählbare Dinge gebraucht werden, zum anderen aber auch als Bezeichnung für das Ding selbst.

> drei Glas Wasser

dies ist eine Mengenangabe - ob das Wasser in einem einzigen Glas oder mit drei verschiedenen Gläsern gemessen wurde, ist irrelevant - Gemeint ist die Menge an Wasser, die in insgesamt drei Gläser passt. Diese Menge Wassers kann man auch in einem Eimer schütten, es ist immer noch "drei Glas Wasser"

> drei Gläser Wasser

zweiteres bezeichnet drei einzelne Gläser voll mit Wasser, die ich z.B. drei Personen zum Trinken anbiete. Schütte ich das gleiche Wasser in einen Eimer, wird es "ein Eimer Wasser" oder "drei Glas Wasser in einem Eimer", die Gläser sind jetzt irrelevant.

Genau dasselbe passiert auch mit "Stück Kuchen" oder "Stück Zucker" - meint man die Menge Kuchens oder Zucker, die drei Stücken entspricht, nimmt man den Singular, meint man drei Kuchenstücke auf einem Teller oder drei Würfelzucker in einer Tasse, nimmt man den Plural.

In der normalen Umgangssprache nimmt man diesen Unterschied allerdings selten so genau - Es kann durchaus sein, dass du das eine für das andere hörst.

Mit "österreichischem" oder "deutschen" Deutsch hat das wenig zu tun - Diese Verwendung (und auch das Mass an Überlappung zwischen den Verwendungen) dürfte überall im deutschen Sprachraum ähnlich sein.

Comment: Mancherorts sagt man auch "3 Stücker Kuchen". ;)

Comment: @userunknown ich kenne das nur als "ungefähr". "Wie viele Jugendliche haben das Fenster eingeworfen?" - "So Stücker drei".

Comment: Im südlichen Schwabenland höre ich dies als *Stucker* (also u statt ü)

Comment: Auch: *Alarm. Drei **Mann** über Bord! Alle **Mann** an Deck!*

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Aber man sagt nicht: Drei Frau über Bord! Alle Frau an Deck! Warum nur? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Bei den von dir zitierten *Mann* handelt es sich nicht um eine Maßeinheit, sodern um einen astreinen Plural, der allerdings heute nur mehr in einigen wenigen Wendungen so verwendet wird. Es gibt mehrere Wörter mit zwei Pluralformen: Wörter-Worte, Länder-Lande, Tücher-Tuche, Rösser-Rosse, Schilder-Schilde, Dinger-Dinge. Bei dem Paar Männer-Manne ist lediglich das endständige e von *Manne* abgefallen. Daher ist *Mann* in »Alle Mann sind zum Rapport angetreten« einfach nur eine der drei Pluralformen von Mann (die dritte Form findet man in: »Er rief seine Mannen zusammen«)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Danke, sehr interessanter sprachhistorischer Blickwinkel. Aber wäre dann *Mannen* nicht einfach die Akkusativform? - Er rief seinen Mannen (Akk) zusammen: "Alle Mann (Nom) an Deck"!

Answer (score 5):

Erstmal: Den Begriff »Österreichisch« sollte man nicht verwenden, weil er nicht klar definiert ist. Es gibt stattdessen:

- **Österreichisches Deutsch**
  Das ist eine standardisierte Hochsprache, das heißt: Diese Sprache wird in Schulen unterrichtet, und in dieser Sprache werden amtliche Dokumente (Gesetze, polizeiliche Niederschriften, Urkunden, ...) verfasst. Es gibt auch ein amtliches Regelwerk für diese Sprache, das ist das ÖWB (Österreichisches Wörterbuch, herausgegeben vom Unterrichtsministerium).  Österreichische Radio- und Fernsehsprecher sprechen diese Sprache. Österreichisches Deutsch unterscheidet sich im Wortschatz (*<del>Quark</del> **Topfen**, <del>Tabakladen</del> **Trafik***), in der Grammatik (*»ich habe Brot <del>für</del> **um** 1 Euro 59 gekauft«*) und in der Aussprache von deutschem Deutsch und von schweizerischem Deutsch. Lediglich die Rechtschreibung ist in allen drei Varietäten dieselbe, allerdings gibt es sogar hier einige wenige Ausnahmen, z.B. deutsches Deutsch: Geschoss (gesprochen mit kurzem o), Küken (mit langem ü); österreichisches Deutsch: Geschoß (langes o), Kücken (kurzes ü). Aber diese Ausnahmen in der Rechtschreibung sind allesamt Folgen der unterschiedlichen Aussprache.
- **Dialekte, die in Österreich gesprochen werden**
  Dialekte sind nicht standardisiert, das heißt, sie werden nirgendwo unterrichtet, und man findet sie nicht in amtlichen Dokumenten. Davon abgesehen werden schon in Wien mehrere verschiedene Dialekte gesprochen (Die Hofratswitwe, die in einer Villa in der Grinzingerstraße residiert, spricht deutlich anders als der Fliesenleger aus dem kaum 200 Meter entfernten Karl-Marx-Hof). Entsprechend vielfältig sind die übrigen österreichischen Dialekte, die sprachwissenschaftlich aber zu den bayrischen Dialekten gehören. Davon ausgenommen ist Vorarlberg, dort werden alemannische Dialekte gesprochen.

Doch zur Frage:

In diesem Punkt unterscheiden sich weder die (mir bekannten) in Österreich gesprochenen Dialekte, noch das österreichische Deutsch, noch das deutsche Deutsch voneinander:

### Maßeinheiten

1. Prinzipiell werden Maßeinheiten nicht flektiert wenn sie hinter Zahlwörtern stehen

   > Mit **20 Euro** wirst du nicht weit kommen.
   >   Irene hat gestern **drei Stück** Zucker genommen.
2. Wenn die folgenden Bedingungen zutreffen, darf die Einheit flektiert werden.

   - Eine Präposition bewirkt, dass die Einheit im Dativ steht.
   - Es handelt sich um eine ungefähre und um eine laienhafte Aussage, also um keine technisch exakte Angabe.
   - Die gezählte oder gemessene Größe steht nicht hinter der Einheit.

   Das ist also erlaubt:

   > Ab einer Entfernung von ca. **drei Metern** sehe ich nicht mehr scharf.

   Aber das muss man nicht machen. Auch das ist daher erlaubt:

   > Ab einer Entfernung von ca. **drei Meter** sehe ich nicht mehr scharf.

   Hier darf aber nicht flektiert werden:

   > Ab **drei Meter** Entfernung sehe ich nicht mehr scharf.

   Grund: Die gemessene Größe (*Entfernung*) steht hinter der Einheit.
3. Einheiten, die weiblich sind und auf e enden, müssen flektiert werden.

   > Die Tonne - Drei **Tonnen** Sand liegen auf dem LKW.
   >   Die Krone - Der Eintritt kostete 30 **Kronen**.
   >   Die Minute - Ich warte hier schon seit 15 **Minuten**.
4. Einheiten, mit denen Zeit gemessen wird, verwendet man immer im Plural.

   > Walters Alter beträgt **37 Jahre**.
   >   Das dauert nun schon **14 Tage**.

---

### keine Maßeinheiten

Viele Wörter, die man als Maßeinheiten verwenden kann, kann man auch in einem anderen Kontext verwenden:

> Diese Woche habe ich mir im Theater gleich drei verschiedene **Stücke** angesehen.

Hier sind Theaterstücke gemeint, und damit wird nichts gemessen. Im Unterschied zu:

> Ich habe gesehen, dass Irene gestern drei **Stück** Zucker in ihren Kaffee gegeben hat.

Hier gibt das Wort *Stück* an, wieviel Zucker verwendet wurde, es ist hier also eine Maßeinheit, und wird daher nach den obigen Regeln behandelt.

Comment: Vielleicht zur besseren Unterscheidung noch das Gegenbeispiel angeben, wie z.B. "..., dass Irene gestern drei **Zuckerstücke**..."

Comment: Duden ist genug (Roy)  und canoo.net umfassend (IQV).
Ich entschuldige mich dafür, dass ich mich nachlässig geäußert habe und nicht  zwischen Dialekten und dem österreichischen "Hochdeutsch" unterschieden habe. 
Liebe Beta, es ist natürlich, dass ich kein Dialekt lernen will, sondern eine Sprache, die ich überall dort einsetzen kann, wo Deutsch gesprochen wird. 
Aiwen